# What does a variable set to "&NULL" means in PHP?

Tags: php, null

I'm working on a tree structure in PHP. When looping through the nodes, an exception is sometime thrown because some node that should not be null is null, more precisely it's set to "&NULL":

```
array(13) {
  // ...
  // some data...
  // ...
  ["segments"]=>
  NULL
  ["leaf"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["children"]=>
  &NULL
}
```

Since it's not inside quotes, I assume it's some kind of special value, but what does it mean?

Comment: For _reference_ (:D), [here are the appropriate docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that it is a reference to a value `NULL`

```
$a = array();

$n = null;
$a[1] =& $n;

var_dump($a); // array(1) { [1]=> &NULL }
```

If you change `$n = null;` to `$n = 1;` - then you'll get `&int(1)`

Comment: This is `value` vs. `reference`, right? Not missing anything in application?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I'm not sure I get you :-S

Comment: I just wonder if `null` is referenced or not, considering the approach. It's not about `null`, it's about the approach. What does PHP allow when it comes to by-value or by-reference? `&` has always troubled me.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: php (as many other programming languages) allows to create "aliases" for the same value in memory. They are called references ;-) It allows to have 2 variable names referred to the same value in memory. So you change the one - and the other is "changed" as well.

Comment: I know what a reference is, but what it is in utility is sometimes different, hence the problem of "by value" and "by reference". This is about PHP's behavior and it's "byzantine" syntax.

Comment: I cannot get you :-( But references behaviour in php is pretty similar to references in c++. I don't see anything special in php

Comment: It's alright, I just don't quite understand how PHP handles references with the `&` operator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11851/discussion-between-zerkms-and-jared-farrish)

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to a value that is null.  "&" is the reference symbol.