# Serialized object coming out with internal value references

Tags: php, oop, object, serialization, reference

This is by far the strangest thing i have seen in PHP, but there surely is some sort of explanation.

Using `serialize()` i am storing some objects. At a later point, i revive them using `unserialize()`.

Today i discovered a problem with an object that has been unserialized. Picture this scenario:

```
object__product_bundle Object (
    [collateralValue] => 
    [collateralGroup] =>
)
```

Now imagine `$obj` to be an instance of `object__product_bundle` as shown above.

When i did:

```
$obj->collateralValue = 10;
```

And checked the object variables, i was shown:

```
object__product_bundle Object (
    [collateralValue] => 10
    [collateralGroup] => 10
)
```

Mindboggling!

I spent an hour smashing my head against the table, as this didn't make sense. But when i started using `var_dump()` on the object, before making changes to it, i saw this:

```
object(object__product_bundle)#28 (15) {
    ["collateralValue"] => &NULL
    ["collateralGroup"] => &NULL
}
```

Apparently these properties/variables were somehow linked. I researched `&NULL` and all i found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792325/what-does-a-variable-set-to-null-means-in-php) which told me i am dealing with some sort of references.

But how?

My object comes from a serialized string.

Now, taking a look at the serialized string i found this:

```
s:15:"collateralValue";N;s:15:"collateralGroup";R:15;
```

What is R:15 ?

Can it be the issue?

How can this problem be addressed and where does it come from?

---

**EDIT**

After digging deeper, i found the culprit.

Orientiation:

The objects (as described above) are stored into a property of another object, which is the item of a shop cart.

```
class shopCart {
    public $storage;
}

$cart->storage[] = new shopCart_item();

class shopCart_item {
    public $object;
}
```

`$object` is where the products (`object__product_*`) are stored.

Upon placing an order, with the aim of being repeated (subscription), this entire `shopCart` is stored into the database as a blob.

Whenever a subscription order is scheduled, an automated task then grabs the old `shopCart` and generates a new order from it.

And here i found the culprit - i added the properties (`collateralValue` etc.) later during development, but there had already been stored orders.

Now during debugging i found that this is where PHP starts creating references, although i do not understand why.

Simply put:

```
static public function generateOrderFromSubscription() {
    [...]
    $order = new object__webShop_order();
    var_dump($subscription->cart); // <-- no references are in here at all
    $order->cart = serialize($subscription->cart);
    var_dump($order->cart); // <-- suddenly, here i have the references
}
```

Apparantely, i use `__sleep()` for each `object__product_*` - which returns those variable names (including `collateralValue` and so on).

The question now becomes then: **Why does PHP create references, when it is dealing with new properties for objects that were asleep but whose structure has changed in the meantime?**

Very confusing!

---

**EDIT #2**

Finally some hope.

My `__sleep()` function basically returned a hardcoded array of variable names, as there were a ton of others i never wanted to store in the database. This approach apparently led to the current problem described in this question.

I still do not know why PHP creates references for variables in objects that were awoken without having those variables at all, but with those variables being returned in `__sleep()`.

The only sensible solution to me, seemed to be to adapt `__sleep()`. I now do this:

```
public function __sleep(){

    $vars=array(
        'dbId',
        'title',
        'articleId',
        'price_per_unit',
    );

    if(isset($this->collateralValue))
        $vars[]='collateralValue';
    if(isset($this->collateralGroup))
        $vars[]='collateralGroup';

}
```

This way, `__sleep()` will not return (any of those two new) variable names (collateralValue, collateralGroup) which are not in use in the current object.

Comment: I think this means that in the original object that you serialized, `$obj->collateralGroup` was a reference to `$obj->collateralValue`. `serialize` knows how to maintain these reference links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let's analyse your serialized string:

```
s:15:"collateralValue";N;s:15:"collateralGroup";R:15;
```

First property (key):

```
s:15:"collateralValue"
```

- `s` just means it is a string
- `15` is the size of the string
- `collateralValue` is the string itself the value (And if you look the string is 15 characters long)

First property (value):

```
N
```

- `N` just mean NULL

Second property (key):

```
s:15:"collateralGroup"
```

- `s` just means it is a string
- `15` is the size of the string
- `collateralGroup` is the string itself the value (And if you look the string is 15 characters long)

Second property (value):

```
R:15
```

- `R` means reference
- `15` means to the 15 value. So here the 15 value is probably the property `collateralValue`, which means if you change the value of it it also changes the value of the `collateralGroup` property

For more information see: http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/serialization.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It is good to learn about the reference in serialization, but my problem remains unsolved. Is there a way to ignore or references when unserializing? Or perhaps to detach or unlink referenced values from one another, after unserializing?

Comment: If you `unset()` or set `$obj->collateralGroup` to anything else it will no longer be a referece to `$obj->collateralValue`

Comment: I wish i could do that. But if it contains a value i need, then this approach will create more problems. The interesting part is that i have nowhere in my code created any kind of reference between those properties, and the values i assign to them are normal integers, not objects (and thus copies of one object). The final question then, i guess, is: how can i unlink those properties without sacrificing the contained values?

Comment: @SquareCat *But if it contains a value i need* How can it contain a value that you need it it is just a reference? Note, that you should unset the second property, so that the reference no longer exists.

Comment: Take a look at _sleep() method -> http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php

Comment: Looking deeper into the matter i realize that i must fix the problem at its root. That means that i must find how in the world PHP got to think i wanted these properties to reference to one another in the first place. There is only one possible origin of the problem that i found though. At a certain point i do this: `foreach($vars as $field=>$value){ this->$field=$value; }` within the object. I wonder how this can cause the issue though.

Comment: @SquareCat That's probably the best to do, since it doesn't seems like you want it to be a reference. (So please edit your question and add your code). Also what is the output of: `var_dump($vars)` before the above code ?

Comment: @SquareCat See my updated comment above ^^: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304012/serialized-object-coming-out-with-internal-value-references#comment50598627_31304269

Comment: I'm trying to get into this, but the code is rather complex and the whole process is triggered in a scheduled manner for orders scheduled for delivery on a certain day.. and so on. Testing this is a pain.

Comment: @SquareCat Then try to dig piece for piece into it. Or post the essential code here. (^ Also check if you have some references in `$vars`, if yes there could be the problem, that you assign a reference to the property)

Comment: Alright, i found the culprit.. sort of. Edited the question. This is becoming an essay.

Comment: @SquareCat Please also add the outputs of the `var_dump()` calls from your edited question. Also show what you do in your `__sleep()` function if you have one

Comment: `var_dump()` outputs are pretty intense. Suffice it to say that when checking the cart before serialization, it contains not even the variables, but after serialization they are around. As for `__sleep()` i think i just found the solution to the problem. I'll edit in a sec.

Comment: @SquareCat I can't really see through your code, since I don't see all of it, but you solved your problem now right ? (Also it still seems like you don't know where it creates the references, and since I can't see it in your code I can only guess, that you maybe assign an object anywhere and they are passed by reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new <- Example #4)

Comment: @SquareCat See the updated comment ^^. Especially look in the link at example 4. I can only guess that you assign an object somewhere, which are always assigned by reference.

Comment: Thank you, yes - the problem is solved by applying the technique i describe in EDIT #2 of my question. The whole thing is still interesting, because none of the properties the problem occured with, are objects.. they are simply values. And how those become a reference is beyond me. It is particularly interesting to note that this only happened with properties which were not part of the object/class when it was initially serialized. Strange behaviour from the side of PHP, imo.

Comment: @SquareCat So my last guess would be that you have a reference laying around in your code and somewhere you overwrite it. As an example what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4969243/3933332 <- If you don't unset the reference in a foreach loop. If you don't have anywhere any references like this, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Same here. At least the problem is solved anyway. Thank you for your strong support!